# Relationship Model between Three Tables in a Fourth Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, data-modeling

So I have two tables -- `Student` table and `Staff` table, I also have an `Item` table, the plan is for students or staff to take custody of an item, put in another way, for an Item to have a custodian (student or staff). So I created a new table -- `Item_Custodian`. How do I model a relationship that would enable my `Item_Custodian` table holds information about an Item and it's custodian be it a student or a staff. Suggestions, tips etc are welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would share three approaches I know for handling such relationships:

- **Approache 1**: Define two separate `nullable foreign keys` in
  `Item_Custodian` one referencing to `Staff` and one referencing to
  `Student` resulting in two physical relationships one of which is
  always `null`.
- **Approach 2**: Define two ranges of Ids for `Student` and
  `Staff` in a way that don't overlap. Then, create only one column in
  `Item_Custodian` and initialize it with either of the two table Ids
  resulting in a logical relationship.
- **Approach 3**: Define two columns in `Item_Custodian` one as a logical foreign key and the other as the type of the first column (i.e. `StaffType` or `StudentType`).

In your scenario where there are only two custodians, I personally prefer the first approach for two reasons:

1. It creates physical relationship between tables
2. Only one `null` column does not make a table sparse

Comment: Crystal clear descriptions, in addition to the reasons you preferred the first approach, I don't have alteration access to either student or staff tables (working in a team). So, the first approach would go well. Thanks